# Timer Ticking down on all Listview items

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

My Timer is ticking down all items in my list view, but i want it to do just the first item.

what i've tried is removing the foreach loop but it wont recognize my items, this little thing is driving me insane!

here is my code:

```
private void ListViewTrainingQue()
{          
   listView1.View = View.Details;
   listView1.GridLines = true;
   listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

   string string2 = "https://api.eveonline.com/char/SkillQueue.xml.aspx?keyID=4602486&&vCODE=BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH";


    // Add Columns to listview 
    listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 50);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Level", 50);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Remaing Time", 100);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Bar", 100);

    // string array1 = "2015-10-23 13:00";

    // Create Array to return values to. 
    string[] arr = new string[3];

    XmlDocument XMLtrans = new XmlDocument();
    XMLtrans.Load(string2);
    XmlNodeList TRnodelist = XMLtrans.SelectNodes("/eveapi/result/rowset/row");
    foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in TRnodelist)
    {     
       string array1 = xmlnode.Attributes["endTime"].InnerText;
       var date1 = DateTime.Parse(array1);
       var Timespan = date1 - DateTime.Now;

       if (xmlnode.Attributes["typeID"] != null)
          arr[0] =  xmlnode.Attributes["typeID"].InnerText;
       if (xmlnode.Attributes["level"] != null)
          arr[1] = xmlnode.Attributes["level"].InnerText;
       if (xmlnode.Attributes["endTime"] != null)
          arr[2] = string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s", Timespan.Hours, Timespan.Minutes, Timespan.Seconds);

       var items = new ListViewItem(arr);
       items.Tag = date1;
       listView1.Items.Add(items);
    }
} 

private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (ListViewItem items in listView1.Items)
   {
      var timeSpan = ((DateTime)items.Tag) - DateTime.Now;
      items.SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);                
   }
}
```

Comment: ?? If you only want to work on the first one, why do you use the loop??  What does the code look like that 'doesn't work' ?? Access the 1st Itms as `ListViewItem item1 in listView1.Items[0]`

Comment: im still learning, do what? if i change " items.SubItems[2].Text" to listview1.items[0].text then it changes the first columns box to the tick. my timer is the the 3rd timer (second array)

Comment: Write what you mean , explain it clearly, listen to the advice you get here! You wrote: _I've tried is removing the foreach loop but it wont recognize my items_ Well I showed you how to access the 1st Item. Try it and rell us the result! - No, the line gives you acces to the 1st ITEM, you still need to modify its subitems..

Comment: `listView1.Items[0].SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s",
                timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);    `

Comment: i swear to god i tried that and it didnt work!!!! :@ but now it is W.T.A.F, submit it as an asnwer and i'll give you brownie points.

Comment: *it didnt work!!!!* - presumably due to `NullReferenceException` when list is empty (`foreach` will work in either case).

Comment: i think i see why it didnt i changed the subitem to [3] :@ and just didnt notice it. welcome to coding! *face palm*